# How to make my PDF File fit the screen in Android PDF library

Tags: android

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    PDFView pdf = (PDFView)findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
    pdf.fromAsset("file.pdf").load();

}
```

This is my java file what to add to fit my file to screen. I am using [bartesc android PDF Library](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer)

Comment: please show activity_home.xml file also, and maybe mockup of what you want

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; xmlns:app="schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"; xmlns:tools="schemas.android.com/tools"; android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context=".HomeActivity"> <com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/pdfView" > </com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView> </RelativeLayout>`  This is my layout file

Comment: You got the answer?